# LINQ Order By on Null Value for integer

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, sql-order-by

I have been able to figure this LINQ thing out a bit more, thanks to the help of the people here. But now, I have come across a new problem, I have not been able to get around...

Here is my code:

```
Dim rfc = From tbl In dt Where tbl(0).Equals(sModel)
                  Select c1 = tbl(0), c2 = tbl(1), c3 = tbl(2), c4 = tbl(3), c5 = tbl(4), c6 = tbl(5), c7 = tbl(6)
                  Order By c2.ToString
```

So... this will order my table as I want, but I now want to insert a second order of sorting, being on c3. But c3 is an integer in a string format, that can also be null (don't ask!). I have tried:

```
Order By c2.ToString, CInt(c3)
```

Now c2 is sometimes null, but the toString function seems to cater for it no problem, but in the event that c3 is null, it throws an error, in that it cannot convert dbull to an integer.

My question is, does anyone know of a way to:
a) allow for this error, or
b) can LINQ perform anything like the Switch function to convert the dbnull at the collection stage of the routine?

All help is much appreciated.

Comment: So what is your criteria for sorting when `null`? For example if `C3` is `3, null, 2`, then what's your expected sorted order?

Comment: E.g. `Order By CStr(c2), If(c3 Is DBNull.Value, Integer.MaxValue, CInt(c3))`.  That will put nulls last and sort the rest in ascending order.

Comment: jmcilhinney, I do not know how to accept your solution, but thank you very much.

Comment: It isn't an answer, it is a comment. You can suggest it be posted as an answer so you can accept.